# How to fill a tensor with matrices one by one?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, tensors, filling

I have this tensor:
[image]

```
nn = 4;
tableToFill = 
Table[x, {p, 1, nn}, {q, 1, nn}, {i, 1, nn}, {j, 1, nn}];
```

that I want to fill with a matrix one by one with a matrix that I get.
 say the first matrix would be in position 1,1 of the tensor so it would be the top left.

It would look something like this:

[image]

I started using a loop but it fills all my matrices with the same numbers.

```
Do[{tableToFill[[row, col]] = newMatrix
  }, {row, 1, nn}, {col, 1, nn}]
MatrixForm[tableToFill]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by generating an array `m` of the appropriate dimensions. The four by four upper block is the 1,1 element of this, so setting m[[1,1]] to the desired 4 by 4 matrix does the trick.

```
m = ConstantArray[0, {4, 4, 4, 4}];
m[[1, 1]] = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {4, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: works thanks :)